# HashMap Data to have new data always

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am having a concurrent hashmap in a method that keeps on taking data continuously. I need to send this data continuously to server. The hashmap is like this -

```
private Map<String, DefaultData> sensorData = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, DefaultData>();

//This is my method for taking data
public void addMethodSensorData(long sensorTypeIdent, long methodIdent1, String prefix, MethodSensorData methodSensorData) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        if (null != prefix) {
            buffer.append(prefix);
            buffer.append('.');
        }
        buffer.append(methodIdent1);
        buffer.append('.');
        buffer.append(sensorTypeIdent);
        sensorData.put(buffer.toString(), methodSensorData);
        Log.d("hi", "methodinvoc" + sensorData);
        //Methods
        List<DefaultData> tempList2 = new ArrayList<DefaultData>(sensorData.values());
        Log.d("hi", "tempList2" + tempList2);
        kry1.sendDataObjects(tempList2);//Data sent to server


}
```

The value of methodIdent1 is different everytime but sensorTypeIdent is same always. The logs coming as of now is -

```
methodinvoc{720.342=com.hi.TimerData@26621ad4}
methodinvoc{2016.342=com.hi.TimerData@7c7b512c, 720.342=com.hi.TimerData@26621ad4}
```

As you see in above logs, the old data is also being added to new data which I dont want.I need logs like this -

```
methodinvoc{720.342=com.hi.TimerData@26621ad4}
methodinvoc{2016.342=com.hi.TimerData@7c7b512c}
```

I dont want the previous data to appear along with new data. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why using a map if there is alyways only one item inside of it?

Comment: Call `sensorData = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, DefaultData>();` instead of `sensorData.clear()` inside the fucntion once after sending to the server.

Comment: I am using MAP because buffer.toString() is different always and also methodSensorData value is also different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the Map to be cleared each time `addMethodSensorData` is invoked, add

```
sensorData.clear();
```

at the start of that method.

```
public void addMethodSensorData(long sensorTypeIdent, long methodIdent1, String prefix, MethodSensorData methodSensorData) {
    sensorData.clear();
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    ...
}
```

Or, if you only use that `Map` inside that method, make `sensorData` a local variable of that method.